# Is there some kind of key combination in Firefox that can mess with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a website, which used to work perfectly fine until some days ago. I was in a hurry that day and probably clicked a key combination that made jQuery/Javascript not work.

At the start, I thought it was a programmatic error and was trying to fix it for several days, then by mistake I checked the website using chrome and IE and in both it worked perfectly correct.

My only conclusion is that I did something and turn jQuery/Javascript off. What's weirder is, I created a new button on that page and made it so on click it will alert something and it works. So it's just half the JS/jQuery that doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea regarding the matter?

To be more specific, is there a key combination that partially disables Javascript or jQuery on Firefox? If so, how do I revert it?

Comment: if you were able to create a new button on that page and make it alert.  Your javascript is working fine

Comment: But nothing else working, and it does work on all other browsers

Comment: Show some code and maybe we can help you

Comment: Do you get a javascript error in your console?

Comment: As it stands this question is off topic. If you'd like to add details of your code and ask for help working out why it's not working correctly, perhaps it can stay.

Comment: amberlamps misspell corrected, I do not get js error

Comment: This seems pretty silly; can't you just try Firefox from another machine?

Comment: Alexander R. if it was a question of code wouldn't it be safe to assume the problem would present itself on all browser?

Comment: pointy that make sense, i will try that now.

Comment: Nope i am wrong it's probably cache in chrome and Firefox

Comment: @NetaMeta If some javascript is running, then it's likely not a browser issue. Regardless, if it's not a question of code it probably shouldn't be on this site. You may wish to have a read through our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see the kinds of questions that we accept.

Comment: Thanks very much and sorry for the un related question.

Comment: I know this post is off topic,  wanted to let people around know(in-case) they didnt. jquery released a new update this month.. if you were including jquery as follow <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> and not a direct link to the file you have on your own server  you can expect problems with your jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that javascript was turned off, since you are able to run an alert, etc. May you post your code? Even so, to enable/disable javascript in Firefox you can do this:

- Tools menu;
- Options item;
- `Content` tab;
- Check "enable javascript" if it is unchecked.

Take a look in Firefox about:config too. My javascript configs are:

[image: javascript configurations of firefox]

P.S. `padrão` means `default` and `número inteiro` means `integer`